# Unable to implement mouse listener

Tags: java, oop, mouselistener

I am trying to implement mouse listener however I can not seem to get it to work.  My code doesnt have any errors, but when I click on the frame I I can not get a message to print out. I have tried extending the class HandleClassOne to viewOne, but that also wouldn't work.  Any thoughts?

The main class creates a frame and then creates an instance of viewOne on the frame.

```
public class main{

  protected static JFrame window;

  public static void main(String args[]){
    window = new JFrame();
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setSize(400,400);    
    window.setVisible(true);    

    new viewOne(window);
 } 
}
```

The viewOne class adds a panel and a label to a frame. It also adds a mouse listener to the panel.

```
public class viewOne {
  private static JPanel panel1;
  private static JLabel label1;

  public viewOne(JFrame frame) {
    panel1 = new JPanel();
    label1 = new JLabel("View One");
    panel1.add(label1);
    frame.add(panel1);
    panel1.setBackground(Color.red);

    frame.validate();
  }

  public static void mouseAdd() {
    HandleClassOne handle = new HandleClassOne();
    panel1.addMouseListener(handle);
    panel1.addMouseMotionListener(handle);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    mouseAdd();
  }
}
```

The HandleClassOne class should print out a message when the panel created in viewOne is clicked.

```
public class HandleClassOne extends main implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("mouse clicked");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While you have defined the function `mouseAdd(...)` I don't see you calling it.

Try (within the constructor)

```
public viewOne(JFrame frame) {
  ...
  mouseAdd();
  ...
}
```

naturally, you'll need to do this after the `panel1` is set.

Note that there are other issues, too

1. You don't invoke presenting the `JFrame` properly within your `main` function in your `main` class.  Look up a basic tutorial on Java Swing, where it talks about the event dispatch thread and the requirements to not present within your program's main thread of execution.
2. You have an additional `main` function in your `viewOne` class, which is not how these things are wired up.

Answer (score 0):

You added the mouseAdd() method (which is responsible for registering the mouse listener) inside the main method of viewOne class.

Please keep in mind that main method only gets called whenever you are running it as entry point class for your application. Here you have main class to act as an entry point.

You kept main method in viewOne class as well and it will get called only when you are running it as an individual piece (not along with main class).

To fix the issue here, keep your mouseAdd() method call inside viewOne() constructor as constructor gets called every time whenever object is getting created.

```
 public viewOne(JFrame frame) {
    panel1 = new JPanel();
    label1 = new JLabel("View One");
    panel1.add(label1);
    frame.add(panel1);
    panel1.setBackground(Color.red);
    mouseAdd();
    frame.validate();
  }
```